# Migrating NSMutableArray initWithContentsOfURL to swift

Tags: ios, url, swift

I am learning Swift and I am trying to re write some of my old apps. Currently I am trying to get the contents of a plist that is stored on my server.

In Objective-C I am using

```
 NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/propertylist.plist"]];
```

and in Swift I am trying

```
var tempArray = NSMutableArray(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://www.mywebsite.com/propertylist.plist")!)
```

I am going to populate a tableview using tempArray but I get nil so I get a fatal error. Can someone tell me the proper way to do this in Swift?

UPDATE

After messing around with it a while longer I decided to try the above code on my device instead of simulator and it worked. I am not sure why it doesn't work on the simulator. Maybe someone knows and can tell me why?

Comment: I think your URL is not correct, you added a dummy code here, it looks ok, but I think there is issue with actual code

Comment: ContentsofURL returns array ?

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus: It depends on the root element

Comment: @thanks Midhun MP I will keep that in mind

Comment: @KumarKL: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/initWithContentsOfURL:

Comment: @MidhunMP : Sorry, I didn't get, what you mean ...? if it is not a kindOf array class . then here considered as NSMutableArray.

Comment: @KumarKL: initWithContentsOfURL returns an NSMutableArray if you are calling that on NSMutableArray. There are a lot of similar methods for various class (like for UIImage, NSData etc each returns corresponding data)

Comment: @MidhunMP Ya, you r right . That's why I questioned, is it the same class type .

Comment: @MidhunMP My URL works in my Objective-C project. I cut and pasted it to the current project. In Objective-C I had this code in viewDidLoad so i did the same with it in Swift. Can that cause the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open a plist file as an Aray when it is actually a Dictionary. You have to do as follow:

```
let plistFileUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.mywebsite.com/propertylist.plist")!

if let plistDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfURL: plistFileUrl){
    if let keyValue = plistDictionary.objectForKey("YourKey") as? String{
        println(keyValue)
    }
}
```